# Making my checkout cart a floating menu that appears when scrolling?

Tags: css, html, checkout, cart, simplecart

How can I make my already existing checkout cart float/follow as i scroll (having the table minimized to save screen space and maximize when clicked if possible would be amazing)

Also, if you could help me with making it magically appear at a certain point in the page, that would definitely be appreciated.

Any help would be great!!!

Current format: http://i265.photobucket.com/albums/ii208/dentyne_fire/untitled_zps88f72bf0.jpg

Code goes as follows:

Cart Div:

```
     <div id="sidebar">
            <h2>Your Cart</h2>


            <!--Add a Div with the class "simpleCart_items" to show your shopping cart area.-->
            <div class="simpleCart_items" >
            </div>


            <!--Here's the Links to Checkout and Empty Cart-->
            <a href="#" class="simpleCart_empty"><font color="#f5d700">empty cart</font></a>
            <a href="#" class="simpleCart_checkout">Checkout</a>



            <!--Nothing below this has to do with simpleCart (js) functionality-->

        <!--End #sidebar--> 
</div>
```

Cart CSS:

```
         <style>

    .cartHeaders,.totalRow{display:none;}
    .simpleCart_items{
        overflow-y:auto;
        overflow-x:hidden;
        height:324px;
        width:243px;
        margin-bottom:20px;

    }
    .itemContainer{
        clear:both;
        width:229px;
        padding:11px 0;
        font-size:11px;
    }
    .itemImage{
        float:left;
        width:60px;
    }
    .itemName{
        float:left;
        width:85px;
    }
    .itemPrice{
        float:left;
        width:85px;
        color:#418932;
    }
    .itemQuantity{
        float:left;
        width:33px;
        margin-top:-12px;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
    .itemQuantity input{
        width:20px;
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        padding:3px 2px;
    }

    .itemTotal{
        float:left;
        color:#c23f26;
        margin-top:-6px
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to do this yourself, or are you just hoping someone can do this all for you?

Comment: Usually it is better to create an simplified version of your issue rather than posting all your code.

Comment: I've attempted to do it/attempting to do it right now... actually even a point in the right direction would help, but I have no problem to keep going at it by myself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't help you making things we can only help you correct things you couldn't manage to do on your own.

What you should do is write a little piece of JavaScript which will check if the user has passed a certain point on your page, you can do that with the `onScroll` event and with the `offsetheight`.

If the user is passed the point then apply the class `fixed` to your checkout, if not then remove the class (don't forget this, users tend to scroll up as well). Next create a fixed CSS class and make sure the cart is positioned correctly on the screen.

Good luck